# In the function extactValues I have to return WeatherValues

Tags: haskell

I have to ask how to fix this

```
Couldn't match type ‘Response String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Response String
```

and this

```
Couldn't match type ‘Response String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Response String
```

in

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module PrepareAnswer where

import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP.Client
import GHC.Generics
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Aeson.Encode.Pretty
import Data.ByteString
import AskWeather
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.ByteString.Char8 

data TempUnits = Celsiuses
               | Farenheits deriving (Generic, Show)

data WeatherValues = WeatherValues
                   { temp_min :: Text
               , temp_max :: Text
               } deriving (Show)

extractValues :: Response String -> WeatherValues
extractValues response =
    let rawJSON = response
        result = decodeStrict (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack rawJSON) :: Maybe Object
    in case result of
        Nothing -> "Invalid JSON!"
        Just info -> WeatherValues temp_min (getTempMin info)

getTempMin :: Object -> Text
getTempMin info =
    case parseMaybe extractTempMin info of
        Nothing -> ""
        Just info -> info
    where
        extractTempMin = \info -> info .: "main"
                         >>=
                         \mainInfo -> mainInfo .: "temp_min"
```

Comment: I think those error messages are pretty clear. You are trying to use your `response` variable which is of type `Response String` as a `String` (`String` and `[Char]` are the same in Haskell). What is a `Response a`?

Comment: @jkeuhlen Response i get in another module. I send a request to the server and get an response. In this case it's information about the weather.

Comment: @jkeuhlen and fow to fix this
Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’
                  with actual type ‘WeatherValues -> Text’

Comment: So if you have a [`Response String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.12/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:Response), how would you get a `String`?

Comment: Ideally, I need this function extractValues :: Response -> WeatherValues but compiler
 Expecting one more argument to    Response
      Expected a type, but    Response    has kind    * -> *
        In the type signature: extractValues :: Response -> WeatherValues

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus down on the part of the code that's giving you this error.

You know how to convert a `String` to a `Maybe Object`. I'm going to extract that to its own function so we can talk about types.

```
convert :: String -> Maybe Object
convert rawJSON =  decodeStrict (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack rawJSON)
```

However in `extractValues` what you're given is a `Response String`, not a `String`. These are fundamentally different types, just like `Maybe Int` and `Int` are.

If you try to do `convert response`, the compiler is going to complain at you because of this type mismatch, so we need to do *something else*.

What *something else* is depends a lot on the API for `Response`.  I assume it's defined in `AskWeather`, so I can only guess, but here's some common patterns that might apply, depending on what that API is.

- If there's a function in `AskWeather` with the type `Response a -> a` or `Response String -> String`, then we need to call that function on the response to extract the `String` from the `Response String`.

  ```
  withExtract :: (Response String -> String) -> Response String -> Maybe Object
  withExtract extract response = convert (extract response)
  ```
- If `Response` is a [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor), there may not be a way to extract a `String` from a `Response String`, but we can use `fmap` to change the `String` it contains into a different type.  This means the return value will still be wrapped in a `Response`

  ```
   asFunctor :: Functor Response => Response String -> Response (Maybe Object)
   asFunctor response = fmap convert response
  ```

Comment: Ok,thanks,but how to fix it?
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’
 with actual type ‘WeatherValues -> Text’
  |
51 |         Just info -> WeatherValues temp_min (getTempMin info)
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^

Comment: I am unable to aid you further without knowing more about `Response`. It's like you're asking me to tell you how to fix your hair without telling me if your hair is straight or kinky, long or short.  I don't know man. It depends.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`Network.HTTP.Client`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.12/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:responseBody), there is a function

```
responseBody :: Response body -> body
```

Note that `body` above can be any type you want, so you can use this to convert a `Response String` into a `String`, as needed.

(I now see that this was already suggested in a comment by @jkeuhlen, which pointed to the relevant documentation.)